# PyGtk3 ~ Allowing a signal from the user, but not the programmatically

Tags: python, signals, infinite-loop, pygobject

My question is related to PyGObject, Gtk3 and signal suppression.

I have a `ComboBoxText`, with a signal connected.

```
self.cbtPaths = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
self.cbtPaths.connect("changed", self.on_changed_path)

def on_changed_path(self,action):
    path = self.cbtPaths.get_active_text()
    i = self.hPaths.change(path)
    self.cbtPaths.set_active(i) #1
```

`self.on_changed_path()` is called when the user changes the `ComboBoxText`.
Which is good.

`on_changed_path()` is called when the code carries out the line marked **#1**.
This causes a never ending loop.

My question is: How do I prevent the line at #1 from triggering the *changed* signal.?

Note: I call `self.cbtPaths.set_active(i)` in another part of the code too.

Comment: I don't think you want to call set_active in your on_changed_path method.  on_changed_path will be called when the selection has changed so there is no need set it again.  I don't understand the relationship of hPaths and cbtPaths.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ditkin,
hPaths is a helper class I wrote which populates the ComboBoxText with new items. These new items are based upon the value the user selected from the ComboBoxText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `handler_block()` and `handler_unblock()`. The former blocks a handler of an instance to not be called during any signal emission.  That handler will be blocked until you unblock it.

You can try something like:

```
self.cbtPaths.handler_block(self.on_changed_path)
self.cbtPaths.set_active(i)
self.cbtPaths.handler_unblock(self.on_changed_path)
```

You can also check [GOBject API's documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--handler-block), although is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

Before set_active, disconnect on_changed_path from cbtPaths changed event. After set_active re-connect it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not to fiddle with the signals at all, but for the handler to check if it should allow itself to be triggered again.

```
def on_cbtPaths_changed(self,action):
    if not self.hPath.is_organised(): #1
        self.hPath.organise()
    else:
        self.btnUpdate.emit("clicked") #2
    return True
```

So when the user, or program, changes the ComboBoxText widget:

- Another class modifies the contents of the ComboBoxText (#1).
- The modification triggers the handler again.
- This time the contents do not need modifying (#2).
- Nothing was modified by #2 so no more signals.